# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, jetty-9

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application war file on standalone jetty. But when I start jetty, I run into this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2909) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindOneToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:3086) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1809) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:911) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:738) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
... 60 common frames omitted
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>configservice</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>configservice Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JPA Provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MS SQL Server JDBC Driver -->
    <!-- Manually install this plugin before adding in POM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc42</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>com.example.model/*.class</includes>
                <excludes>**/entities/XML*.class</excludes>
                <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
                <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enhancer</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
                    <!-- set the version to be the same as the level in your runtime -->
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>configservice</finalName>
</build>
```

I am using OpenJPA along with Spring-Data in this spring boot application. I have searched stackoverflow for similar errors and I found couple of resolutions from them and none of them has worked in my case. I can see the error is coming because somewhere JPA 2.0 is getting used. How can I find out which library is using JPA 2.0 and remove this error? If I run the same Spring boot app through maven with embedded jetty, it works perfectly fine.

I have looked at these links 
[Hibernate NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550463/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-joincolumn-foreignkey)
[Spring boot NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373725/spring-boot-hibernate-error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-joinc)

Comment: Why do you have OpenJPA as persistence provider in your dependencies? spring-boot-starter-data-jpa uses Hibernate by default

Comment: OpenJPA offers better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use OpenJPA instead of Hibernate in Spring Boot you must exclude hibernate-entitymanager

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

And then configure OpenJPA as persistence provider.

Please find a example with EclipseLink here:
http://blog.marcnuri.com/spring-data-jpa-eclipselink-configuring-spring-boot-to-use-eclipselink-as-the-jpa-provider/

Comment: I get this error if I add that exclusion - "Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration."

Comment: Have you read this article. http://blog.marcnuri.com/spring-data-jpa-eclipselink-configuring-spring-boot-to-use-eclipselink-as-the-jpa-provider/